# Columnwise pandas apply and return new dataframe with index from one func argument

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I want to apply a pre-defined function to all columns of a pandas dataframe without looping through the list of strings representing the columns (which are countries here). The function uses the original dataframe on which it is applied, `df_exposure`, as well as information from another dataframe, `df_life_expectancy`.

Example data for the dataframes:

```
frame_exposure = {
    'Canada': np.random.randint(1,9,154),
    'USA': np.random.randint(1,9,154),
    'Mexico': np.random.randint(1,9,154),
}

df_exposure = pd.DataFrame(frame_exposure,index=np.arange(1960,2114))

frame_expectancy = {
    'Canada': np.random.randint(60,80,61),
    'USA': np.random.randint(60,80,61),
    'Mexico': np.random.randint(60,80,61),
}

df_life_expectancy = pd.DataFrame(frame_expectancy,index=np.arange(1960,2021))
```

My function should loop through a country's life expectancy data from `df_life_expectancy` to sum lifetime exposure for each column/country (`col`):

```
def calc_life_exposure(
    df_exposure,
    df_life_expectancy,
    col,
):


    # initialise birth years 
    exposure_birthyears_percountry = np.empty(len(df_life_expectancy))

    for i, birth_year in enumerate(df_life_expectancy.index):

        life_expectancy = df_life_expectancy.loc[birth_year,col] 

        # define death year based on life expectancy
        death_year = birth_year + np.floor(life_expectancy)

        # integrate exposure over full years lived
        exposure_birthyears_percountry[i] = df_exposure.loc[birth_year:death_year,col].sum()
        
        # add exposure during last (partial) year
        exposure_birthyears_percountry[i] = exposure_birthyears_percountry[i] + \
            df_exposure.loc[death_year+1,col].sum() * \
                (life_expectancy - np.floor(life_expectancy))
    
    # a series for each column to somehow group into a dataframe
    exposure_birthyears_percountry = pd.Series(
        exposure_birthyears_percountry,
        index=df_life_expectancy.index,
        name=col,
    )
    
    return exposure_birthyears_percountry
```

Ideally, I'd then like to run this in apply to return a new dataframe (`df_test`) with the same shape as `df_life_expectancy', which currently looks like:

```
df_test = df_exposure.apply(
    lambda col: calc_life_exposure(
        df_exposure,
        df_life_expectancy,
        col,
    ),
    axis=0,
)
```

But this does not work:

```
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([1, 7, 1, 6, 6, 8, 2, 5, 8, 8,\n            ...\n            7, 5, 8, 1, 8, 3, 2, 6, 7, 6],\n           dtype='int64', length=154)] are in the [index]"
```

Comment: what  happens if you change axis=1 in the apply

Comment: Another error: `KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([1, 7, 2], dtype='int64')] are in the [index]"`

Answer (score 1):

Fix your code:

```
df_test = df_exposure.apply(
    lambda col: calc_life_exposure(
        df_exposure,
        df_life_expectancy,
        col.name # Here you need to pass the name of column
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I had some uncertainties about the meaning of `col` in the lambda function, which I only understood from some context in seeing other `lambda row: ...` applications. Also surprised I was this close...